# Delete created div js

Tags: javascript, html

Tell me please, there is code, when you click on select option, a div is added. Please help me add a delete button next to each created div and delete this div.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("inputi");
var length = 1;

function add_input_from_select(select) {
  var new_input = document.createElement("input");
  new_input.name = "my_input";
  new_input.value = select.value;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = '<br>div элемент №' + length + '<br>';
  div.appendChild(new_input);
  p.appendChild(div);
  length++;
}

function add_input_old() {
  add_input_from_select(document.getElementById("selector"));
}
```

```html
<select id="selector" onchange="add_input_from_select(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<form>
  <div id="inputi"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very crudely, you can add a `button` in the same way you are currently adding an `input` and a `div` but bind a click event to the `button` so that when clicked it deletes it's parent and everything inside it.

```js
var p = document.getElementById("inputi");
var length = 1;

function add_input_from_select(select) {
  var new_input = document.createElement("input");
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var button_delete = document.createElement('button');
  
  new_input.name = "my_input";
  new_input.value = select.value;
  button_delete.innerText = "Delete"
  button_delete.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.parentNode.remove();
  });
  div.innerHTML = '<br>div элемент №' + length + '<br>';
  div.appendChild(new_input);
  div.appendChild(button_delete);      
  
  p.appendChild(div);
  length++;
}

function add_input_old() {
  add_input_from_select(document.getElementById("selector"));
}
```

```html
<select id="selector" onchange="add_input_from_select(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<form>
  <div id="inputi"></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the things I have created to achieve your goal

- Created a delete button and appended it to the div
- Created an `onclick` event for the delete button and deleted the current div using `display:none`

```js
var p = document.getElementById("inputi");
var length = 1;
var deleteBtn;
function add_input_from_select(select) {
  var new_input = document.createElement("input");
  new_input.name = "my_input";
  new_input.value = select.value;
  var div = document.createElement('div');

  deleteBtn = document.createElement('button'); //Adding delete button
  deleteBtn.innerHTML = 'Delete';
  deleteBtn.setAttribute("type", "button"); 

  div.innerHTML = '<br>div элемент №' + length + '<br>';
  div.appendChild(new_input);
  div.appendChild(deleteBtn);
  deleteBtn.setAttribute("onclick", function() { alert("blabla"); });
  p.appendChild(div);
  length++;

  deleteBtn.onclick = function(){  //Event for deleting the div
 div.style.display = "none";
 }

}
```

```html
<select id="selector" onchange="add_input_from_select(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<form>
  <div id="inputi"></div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although your question was framed in a way that it was difficult to understand what you want, I think I've got it.

I think it would be **MUCH** easier if you tried to do this in jQuery. Here's a very simple way to do it (I've added some comments incase you are new to jQuery) -

1 - Create the snippet code that you want to add to the DOM. (You just needed an extra button element in yours).
2 - use jQuery for manipulating DOM based on click and change events.

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $('#selector').change(function() {
   // getting the input tag ready with value from selector
   $divToAppend = '<div><input type="text" value="'+$(this).val()+'"><button type="button" id="btn-delete">Remove</button></div>'
    // appending the div to the form
   $('form').append($divToAppend);
  });
  // binding a function to EVERY btn-delete ID in the 'form' scope
  $('#form').on('click', '#btn-delete', function() {
  // this goes to the btn-delete, looks for it's parent, which is the <div> and the removes it from the DOM
   $(this).parent().remove();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
  <option selected hidden>Select something!</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<form id="form">

</form>
```